# Alpha component on UIBezierPath Fill

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, uicolor, alpha-transparency

I have a view defined like this :

```
class TriangleView: UIView {


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // Get Height and Width
    let layerHeight = self.layer.frame.height
    let layerWidth = self.layer.frame.width

    // Create Path
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

    bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, layerHeight))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(layerWidth, layerHeight + 4))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
    bezierPath.closePath()

    // Apply Color
    UIColor(red: (69/255.0), green: (209/255.0), blue: (153/255.0), alpha: 1.0).setFill()
    bezierPath.fill()

    // Mask to Path
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer

}

}
```

I'm trying to make it semi-transparent, however using `UIColor(red: (69/255.0), green: (209/255.0), blue: (153/255.0), alpha: 0.5).setFill()` as well as using `bezierPath.fillWithBlendMode( .Normal, alpha: 0.5)` produces the same result of a darker than normal color with no transparency, the more I decrease the `alpha` in both cases, the darker the color becomes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the views `backgroundColor` to `UIColor.clearColor()`.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have guessed that! 

Comment: I had it set to default thinking it was equivalent..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning the **TriangleView** for the main view which present on the **ViewController**. Instead of that drag another **view** from the **Object Library** and assign it as **TriangleView**